# Why does Mongoose insert null as the last element of the subdocuments array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I have a Mongoose schema with an array of subdocuments, that looks like this:

```
const cardsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  cards: [
    {
      front: String,
      back: String,
      nameOfSuperset: String,
      nameOfSet: String,
    },
  ],
});

const Cards = mongoose.model("Cards", cardsSchema);
```

I have created a document from the above model, and I am pushing a couple of objects in the array of subdocuments of this document:

```
exports.createCards = async (req, res, next) => {

  const userCards = await Cards.findById(req.user.cards);

  for (let i = 0; i < req.body.cards.length; i++) {
    userCards.cards.push(req.body.cards[i]);
  }

  const created = await userCards.save();
  console.log(created);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
  });
};
```

When I console.log this saved document, or look at it in MongoDB Compass, there is **null** in the document at the end of the subdocuments array. I am not pushing any empty objects in this document. The original array, from which I get objects to push (req.body.cards) doesn't have null elements or empty objects. I have console.logged it. [image]

What is this null and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: you can use a `updateOne` with `$push` and `$each` operator to push documents in array. [refer example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#use--each--with--push-operator).

Comment: replace for with forEach and try

Comment: @mohammadNaimi It worked. Thank you. I`m just curious what is the problem with for loop?

Comment: @turivishal `await Cards.updateOne({ _id: req.user.cards }, { $push: { cards: { $each: req.body.cards } } });` works. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: if it possible to make an answer and accept it?if the problem has been solved it was from loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `for` loop with `forEach`

```
req.body.cards.forEach(item=>{
userCards.cards.push(item)
})
```